# How to subset a matrix using a large character vector

Tags: r, vector, character, subset

I am quite new to R and I am working with a large genomic matrix and I am preparing heatmaps using certain genes. I subset a matrix containing the genes of my interest.

I tried to do it this way:

```
vector_infertility_genes <- infertility$V1

matrix_for_heatmap_infertility <- subset(my_genomic_matrix, vector_infertility_genes)
```

But this gives me just the first x number of rows from my matrix where x is the number of characters I have in vector_infertility genes.

So far I was able to dodge this problem by doing something like this:

```
matrix_for_heatmap_infertility <- my_genomic_matrix[c('EPHX1', 'HSPB1', 'CLU', 'GAMT',  'PICK1', 'NR3C1',
                                                                 'SIRT1', 'NPAS2', 'SPRY4', 'MAP3K1', 'SOS1', 'SALL4', 
                                                                 'GRIP1', 'PUM2', 'SOX9', 'RIPK4', 'CHD7',  'BCOR', 
                                                                 'CCNB1', 'NFE2L2', 'CHD2', 'CYP1B1', 'MDM2', 'CREBBP',
                                                                 'ICK', 'ZFY', 'SIN3A', 'GATA4'), ]
```

If I will have to manually type the rowname of every gene to subset like this again I will kill myself. Is there an easier way to do this with creating a character vector and using it to subset?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. I would recommend the folllowing (guideline)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example] before posting to make the most of the stackoverflow community. Yes whatever the way you need to find a way to tell which rows are you interested in. May be there is a specific classification of the genes ids that you haven't mentioned. If so you need to look into [data.table](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html )package.to merge the the rownames with something you can easily relate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a guess at the problem. Your genes are factors, and when you use them to subset a matrix, they are converted to numeric:

```
genes = c('EPHX1','HSPB1', 'CLU', 'GAMT','PICK1', 'NR3C1','SIRT1', 'NPAS2',
'SPRY4', 'MAP3K1', 'SOS1', 'SALL4','GRIP1', 'PUM2', 'SOX9', 'RIPK4', 'CHD7', 
'BCOR','CCNB1','NFE2L2', 'CHD2', 'CYP1B1', 'MDM2', 'CREBBP', 'ICK', 'ZFY',
'SIN3A', 'GATA4')

class(genes)
[1] "character"

infertility = data.frame(V1=genes)
vector_infertility_genes <- infertility$V1

class(vector_infertility_genes)
[1] "factor"
```

By default, the data.frame has characters as a vector, now below I make a matrix with some random gene names, and insert the chosen genes from 101-128:

```
my_genomic_matrix = matrix(runif(1000*3),ncol=3)
rownames(my_genomic_matrix) = paste0("gene",1:1000)
rownames(my_genomic_matrix)[101:128] = genes
```

This gives you some weird thing:

```
head(my_genomic_matrix[vector_infertility_genes,])
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
gene8  0.6705400 0.92836211 0.39245031
gene12 0.6550523 0.87094037 0.08309788
gene5  0.3737798 0.94779178 0.44279510
gene9  0.4544450 0.77939541 0.13901245
gene19 0.6284895 0.47871950 0.60837784
gene18 0.2369957 0.01336282 0.10390174
```

This should work in most cases, as long as you are sure your vector_infertility_genes are in the row names of my_genomic_matrix:

```
head(my_genomic_matrix[as.character(vector_infertility_genes),])
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
EPHX1 0.1380852 0.91638593 0.5155086
HSPB1 0.4828377 0.44798223 0.6011990
CLU   0.7974677 0.84083760 0.4378384
GAMT  0.9654133 0.04167125 0.6087020
PICK1 0.1958134 0.22254847 0.5157768
NR3C1 0.4228220 0.14512706 0.6136789
```

If some are missing you can also do:

```
vector_infertility_genes = as.character(vector_infertility_genes)
my_genomic_matrix[rownames(my_genomic_matrix) %in% vector_infertility_genes,]
```